# Command conditional upon file name with loop

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am trying to create a macro that runs a command on a bunch of xlsm workbooks. These workbooks are named with numbers (e.g. 11.xlsm, 12.xlsm, 13.xlsm etc) and I would like the macro to run a simple command on worksheet ("1") of every workbook with a loop. The command simply consists of clearing the content of a cell and writing something which varies depending on the workbook name.

I've given it a go but without success. Also, I get the following error "object doesn't support this property or method".

Your help would be much appreciated.

```
Sub IDCell()

    Dim wbpath As String
    Dim wbnames() As String
    Dim ext As String
    Dim wbTarget As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rgID As Range

    ext = ".xlsm"
    wbpath = "Z:\\User\Documents"
    wbnames() = Split("11,12,13", ",")  

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To UBound(wbnames)
      Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(wbpath & "\" & wbnames(i) & ext)

     For x = 1 To 1

      If wbTarget = "11.xslm" Then
        Set ws = Worksheets(CStr(x))
        ws.Activate
        Set rgID = ws.Range("K4:K4")
        rgID.ClearContents
        rgID.Value = "XXXX"
      End If

      If wbTarget = "12.xslm" Then
        Set ws = Worksheets(CStr(x))
        ws.Activate
        Set rgID = ws.Range("K4:K4")
        rgID.ClearContents
        rgID.Value = "YYYY"
      End If           

      If wbTarget = "13.xlsm" Then
        Set ws = Worksheets(CStr(x))
        ws.Activate
        Set rgID = ws.Range("K4:K4")
        rgID.ClearContents
        rgID.Value = "ZZZZ"
      End If

     Next    

    wbTarget.Save   
    wbTarget.Close   

   Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: if you debug your code you see that the error occurred on row If wbTarget = "11.xslm" Then... wbTarget what is?!?!? try to debug.print wbTarget and try debug.print wbTarget.name. You'll see that wbTarget.name will be comparable to your string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem was you need `wbTarget.Name` instead of `wbTarget`, but standing your narrative you can:

- avoid looping over x
- avoid If-Then-Else

like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub IDCell()
    Dim wbPath As String, ext As String
    Dim wbNames As Variant
    Dim wbValues As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    ext = ".xlsm"
    wbpath = "Z:\\User\Documents"
    wbNames = Array(11, 12, 13) '<--| set an array of your workbook names
    wbValues = Array("XXXX", "YYYY", "ZZZZ") '<--| set an array of texta to be written in each corresponding workbook 

    For i = 0 To UBound(wbNames) '<--| loop over workbook names
        With Workbooks.Open(wbPath & "\" & wbNames(i) & ext).Worksheets("1").Range("K4") '<--| open workbook and assume as reference the range "K4" of its "1" worksheet
            .ClearContents
            .Value = wbValues(i)
        End With
        ActiveWorkbook.Close True '<--| close active workbook and save it
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten your block of:

```
For x = 1 To 1

  If wbTarget = "11.xslm" Then
    Set ws = Worksheets(CStr(x))
    ws.Activate
    Set rgID = ws.Range("K4:K4")
    rgID.ClearContents
    rgID.Value = "XXXX"
  End If

  If wbTarget = "12.xslm" Then
    Set ws = Worksheets(CStr(x))
    ws.Activate
    Set rgID = ws.Range("K4:K4")
    rgID.ClearContents
    rgID.Value = "YYYY"
  End If           

  If wbTarget = "13.xlsm" Then
    Set ws = Worksheets(CStr(x))
    ws.Activate
    Set rgID = ws.Range("K4:K4")
    rgID.ClearContents
    rgID.Value = "ZZZZ"
  End If

 Next
```

to

```
    wbTarget.Sheets("1").Range("K4").value = iif(wbnames(i)="11","XXXX",iif(wbnames(i)="12","YYYYY","ZZZZZ"))
```

Comment: If you need more options late on you should use `Select case wbTarget.name`, `Case "11.xlsm` etc.

Comment: Thanks for your input.